# How can I find whether each value in a list fits the criteria or not?

Tags: python, list

So I created a code to find prime numbers, and my `is_prime(k):` function works, however when I'm trying to find all the prime numbers in a given list as indicated in `prime(number):` it doesnt work. Can someone give me examples to draw from?

Comment: Note that `sqrt(n)` is a MUCH smaller upper bound to use for trial division when checking for primality as `n` grows large.

Answer (score 3):

Use your `is_prime` function:

```
def sans_primes(numbers):
    return [n for n in numbers if is_prime(n)]
```

Or to only get the unique values:

```
def sans_primes(numbers):
    return set(n for n in set(numbers) if is_prime(n))
```

Comment: is there any other way that is possible for me to do this?? Your code is great and it definitely works, but sadly my initial code was too similar to others so I had to delete it... is there any other way for me to do it, if yes, please give me an example, so I can draw ideas from it. Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by "*similar to others*"? If I remember well, your method was good, check potential factors up to sqrt(n), if the remainder of division is 0, break this is not a prime, else this is a prime